# Backslash (\) keyboard shortcut (ctrl+alt+#) not working in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

This is driving me insane and I can't figure it out. Problem only occurs in the code editors (C#, VB, XML etc). It works in other places in Visual Studio (e.g. in work item tabs).

I've checked keyboard shortcuts and it's not mapped to anything. It works fine in other visual studio's (e.g. 2019). It works fine in Visual Studio 2022 of a different version on a different computer, with the same personalisation account logged in. I've also tried the "repair" option to no avail. Any ideas as this is driving me nuts because my keyboard doesn't have a blackslash button (when I plug in a keyboard with a backlash button it works fine).

Comment: Do you have a numpad? Try holding Alt then  type 92 using the numpad numbers.

Comment: @TimothyG. Not on the keyboard in question (it's an 84%). I've just swapped keyboards for now but ideally would like to know what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be a bug introduced somewhere between 17.5.4 - 17.6.5. I upgraded my version where this worked to 17.6.5 and also encountered this bug, even with a different personalisation account logged in

Edit - I raised this on MS developer forum. They've now fixed this and it's pending release.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ctrlalt-not-working-Visual-Studio/10427391

Comment: FYI, this space is for answers, but what you posted looks more like additional info or clarification, which then belongs in the question (which you can edit).

Comment: My question was just asking why something wasn't working. After some testing across different machines and versions it appears to be a bug in Visual Studio. Is that not an answer to why it's not working? I know that there is no "fix" included in my answer but that's not really in my hands at this point and I'm not after a workaround (e.g. using alt + numpad 9 + numpad 2) because my keyboard doesn't have a numberpad. Appreciate the heads up nonetheless.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).